# JMeter won't start when using customized JRE

Tags: java, jmeter

I've problems when I try to run JMeter Java Request Sampler tests. We are using a modified IBM JRE in our company and I cannot start JMeter at all using it. If I try, I get an error:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:275)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:69)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:540)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$300(URLClassLoader.java:79)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$ClassFinder.run(URLClassLoader.java:1034)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:284)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:429)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:653)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:619)
at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:172)
at org.apache.jorphan.reflect.ClassFinder.isChildOf(ClassFinder.java:465)
at org.apache.jorphan.reflect.ClassFinder.access$000(ClassFinder.java:46)
at org.apache.jorphan.reflect.ClassFinder$FilterTreeSet.add(ClassFinder.java:106)
at org.apache.jorphan.reflect.ClassFinder$FilterTreeSet.add(ClassFinder.java:63)
at org.apache.jorphan.reflect.ClassFinder.findClassesInOnePath(ClassFinder.java:532)
at org.apache.jorphan.reflect.ClassFinder.findClassesInPaths(ClassFinder.java:548)
at org.apache.jorphan.reflect.ClassFinder.findClassesThatExtend(ClassFinder.java:291)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.populateCommandMap(ActionRouter.java:257)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.getInstance(ActionRouter.java:300)
at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.startGui(JMeter.java:231)
at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.start(JMeter.java:380)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:259)
```

I tried a workaround and compiled my Java test using our modified JRE. Then I put needed jars in JMeter's lib\ext folder but when I tried to run test in JMeter using standard IBM JRE (JMeter works with this JRE) I get an error:

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: org.omg.CORBA.Environment
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:143)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:700)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$400(URLClassLoader.java:81)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$ClassFinder.run(URLClassLoader.java:1148)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:583)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:756)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:733)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:703)
at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:219)
at org.apache.jorphan.reflect.ClassFinder.isChildOf(ClassFinder.java:465)
at org.apache.jorphan.reflect.ClassFinder.access$000(ClassFinder.java:46)
at org.apache.jorphan.reflect.ClassFinder$FilterTreeSet.add(ClassFinder.java:106)
at org.apache.jorphan.reflect.ClassFinder$FilterTreeSet.add(ClassFinder.java:63)
at org.apache.jorphan.reflect.ClassFinder.findClassesInOnePath(ClassFinder.java:532)
at org.apache.jorphan.reflect.ClassFinder.findClassesInPaths(ClassFinder.java:548)
at org.apache.jorphan.reflect.ClassFinder.findClassesThatExtend(ClassFinder.java:291)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.populateCommandMap(ActionRouter.java:257)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.getInstance(ActionRouter.java:300)
at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.startGui(JMeter.java:231)
at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.start(JMeter.java:380)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:76)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:607)
at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:259)
```

Any ideas how I could get this working?

Comment: Looks like not using standard JRE has come back to bite your ass...

Answer (score 0):

You ibm jvm needs to be java6 compatible if using recent jmeter versions.

JMeter works fine even with IBM jvms provided the good versions are used.